# how to create LWUIT res file?

Tags: java-me, resources, lwuit

```
Resources res = Resources.open("/myTheme.res");
UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(res.getTheme("myTheme"));
```

hi I need to open my resource file in LWUIT but how to create a resource file in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this and check your resource file work place also.

UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(
             res.getTheme(res.getThemeResourceNames()[0]));

Comment: is there any software available for this purpose as well?

Comment: LWUIT 1.4 ResourceEdit having all designing features. But if u want to new ResourceEdit means see this link and click the launch in key features, https://lwuit.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

There is also some excellent tutorials on how to create a LWUIT resource file on the Shais LWUIT blog

http://lwuit.blogspot.com/search/label/LWUIT%20GUIBuilder%20ResourceEditor%20tutorial